# Scripting with Batch Files in DOS (NT) Windows Server 2008

Tags: file, batch-file, scripting, dos

I'm trying to go around the loop a fixed number of times, however I find I cannot seem to make this statement work with

```
REM @echo off
SET TotalCores=12
SET Sockets=2
SET SlaveNodes=4
SET /A mycores = %TotalCores% / %SlaveNodes%
FOR /L %i in (0,1,%SlaveNodes%) DO (call slavenode.bat  %i %mycores)
```

Why do I get the following issue?

```
SET /A mycores = 12 / 4
SlaveNodesi was unexpected at this time.
```

Is my formatting correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces, and use double percent signs around your loop variable:

```
REM @echo off
SET TotalCores=12
SET Sockets=2
SET SlaveNodes=4
SET /A mycores=%TotalCores%/%SlaveNodes%
FOR /L %%i in (0,1,%SlaveNodes%) DO (call slavenode.bat  %%i %mycores%)
```

Comment: `set /a` has no problems with the spaces. (while a simple `set` will make trouble...)

Comment: set /a didn't like the spaces either between the var names and assignment (`=`). It just caused a slightly different error.

Comment: One of the other issues is now how to pass in the number of cores. I'm having trouble with the accessing the number of cores using %2 in my slavenode.bat file.

Comment: @KenWhite: I have no problem with the spaces in Win7. @user673600: there is a `%`missing in this code. See my answer.

Comment: @Stephen: You're right; I missed one with the copy/paste. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

in batch files you must use double percentsigns for the for-variables:

```
FOR /L %%i in (0,1,%SlaveNodes%) DO (call slavenode.bat  %%i %mycores%)
```

(also you missed a `%` with your variable %mycores%)